# Restore database from a save

Tags: postgresql, restore

I use pgadmin 4 and PostgreSQL

I try to restore a database from a save.

I have put the directory of my file save `C:\Users\H2O\Desktop\temp_DB\` as a binary path in file preferences.

When I try to restore my db from my tar file (database -> restore) I have got this error.

> 'C:\Users\H2O\Desktop\temp_DB\pg_restore.exe' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne (pg_restore is not recognize as an internal command)

Don't know where it comes from.

---

I use pg admin 4 and Postgresql

---

'"C:/Users/Public/Downloads/tempDB/ \pg_restore.exe"' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne

Answer (score 1):

The Binary Path in <kbd>Preferences</kbd> is for the Postgres binaries, *not* for the backup file. Revert the Binary Path to the default (probably `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\$version\bin` where you replace `$version` as appropriate for your installation).

Enter the path to the backup file in the <kbd>Tools > Restore</kbd> dialogue and not in <kbd>Preferences</kbd>.

Comment: In tools->restore i give the path to my file but it doesnt worksC:/Users/Public/Downloads/tempDB/ \pg_restore.exe --host "localhost" --port "5433" --username "postgres" --no-password --role "postgres" --dbname "dvdrental" --format=d --verbose "C:/tempDB/restore.sql"

Comment: @user182824 it looks like you still need to update the path to the binaries in `Preferences`, which is the important bit